# Seat belt / airbag light ON polo 2013

Tags: vw, body, polo, seat-belt, obd-ii

Hello I have a polo from 2013. I just inherited it from my grandfather, whom has not driven it that much. Most of the time it has been in garage. Only done 28.000 km

After I got it a lamp started lighting up. The airbag-seatbelt lamp, is yellow.

I therefore have investigated under the seats where I found an umbrella. Hoping that it had interfered with the signals, I tried ensuring that all the plugs where firmly connected. I believe one may not have been, but the light is still on.

I acquired an ODB reader for the ODB plug, but it only reads error messages in respect to the engine, i.e. not helpful.

I then acquired the Haynes manual, which states in the body section that there is plug behind the air control for the driverside. I have tried following the manual to remove the cover to see the "wished-to-be" ODB-plug. But I am affraid of using excessive force.

My question is therefore is there a way to read error messages using ODB for the body-system of the car, not the engine ECU?
Am I on the right track with the above mentioned plug hidden behind a airflow control?

Do I have to throw in the towel and pay my "fine" to the mechanic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding someone who has VCDS would be your easiest method of finding out what is happening.  That will be able to read the body computer. Look around locally for a VW car club.

With VCDS you will read through the normal ODBII cable, and on a computer you will have the ability to read codes, status, etc. on the body computer.

A well equipped shop may have that software and cable, or another proprietary scan package.  Of course your "fine" will apply.

Comment: Hmm, sad. There are no VCDS do-it-yourself system you can recommend. Have searched a little after you gave the term. But seems expensive and others have very mixed review.

Comment: Look at the options Ross-Tech offers.  I have one of theirs.

Comment: Also some of the fancier code readers read body, ABS and transmission codes.  However, for VW, I have found VCDS the best buy, and the forums, such as Fred's TDI tend to cover using it there.  The Ross-Tech site also has diagnostic info which might help. I am sorry, but my bentley book doesn't cover the Polo, but I could probably send you what is in it and wiring diagrams, etc. might be similar.

Comment: Just saw a youtube video on the ODBeleven product.  Lower cost than VCDS.  I cannot say if it will do what you need, but they advertise that it will talk to the major controllers.  Perhaps you might check that product out.

Comment: I have looked at it now and seems very interesting, I have also found a DIY place where they should have similar systems that I will investigate, to see what possibilities exist. Thank you for all your help and insight

Comment: good luck and let us know what you find out.  Some of the online forums have users who make their VCDS available.  See if someone in your area might be willing to help.  I have helped dozens of people read their codes, and sometimes diagnose their problems.  Having someone familiar with the tool takes less time as well.