# VW Golf 5 FSI Jerks When Driving

Tags: engine, electrical, vw, driving

Please help. I have recently serviced my VW Golf 5 with air cleaner,oil filter,fuel filter and plugs but the car still jerks most times when driving. I had it diagonised and gave me  error codes P1403 Exhaust Gas Recirculation :control difference & P2540 Low pressure fuel system sensor circuit (ALL IMPLAUSSIBLE SIGNALS). What exactly am I supposed to do? Change certain sensors? Change Fuel pump? Change gear box as the jerking seems to have something to do with gear box engaging.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Can you better describe what you're talking about by "jerking"? Is it vering left/right? Is it engine power we're talking about? Is this a standard or automatic transmission?

Comment: It is an automatic vehicle and by jerking I want to mean behaving like being propelled forward and backwards at the same time. No it is not vering to the left or right

Comment: Why do you consider the P2540 code as implausible? Did you clear the codes and see if they came back?

Comment: Diagonistic person performed the work and results on the machine read ' Implaussible sig' yes. He had 3 errors coming up buy said he managed to delete one other and these 2 remained -P2540 & P1403

Comment: I mean he initially had 3 errors but only managed to delete one but error codes P2540 and P1403 could not be deleted. I personally saw the 'implaussible signal' result against each error.

Comment: Please don't type USING ALL CAPITALS, as in your question's title. It's seen as SHOUTING, and is disliked. It will discourage answers, not encourage them.

Comment: Thank you. I have learnt something and will avoid using capitals.

Answer (score 0):

"Implaussible signal" does NOT mean the code can be ignored.  It usually means the battery is weak or there was a voltage drop somewhere [when the code was stored](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/46339/why-does-my-vw-diagnostic-codes-give-implausible-signal), as is the case during startup.  You may want to have the battery tested at an auto parts store and clean the battery cables, ground straps, and other related connections.

The P1403 means the EGR valve should most likely be replaced.  It tends to get dirty and clogged with soot on VWs.

P2540 is probably a result of code P1403.  As the engine bucks and hesitates, the fuel pressure drops (or varies at least).  I would replace the EGR valve first and see if P2540 clears by itself.

Comment: Thank you so much your advise. I will first take the above steps and see if the problem will be sorted out. I then will definitely post a fed back so that others can also learn from it. God bless.

Comment: You're welcome.  I would love the hear how you resolved the problem.